# How to find the Lie algebra of $G:=\{A\in GL_2(\Bbb{R}): A^tQA=Q\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, lie-algebras

> Let $Q:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $G:=\{A\in GL_2(\Bbb{R}): A^tQA=Q\}$. I want to find the Lie algebra of $G$.

I know that by definition $Lie(G):=\{X: \exp(tX)\in G ~~\forall t\in \Bbb{R}\}$. And I also know that one has the characterization that $Lie(G)=T_I(G)$ which is the tangent space of $G$ at identity $I$. I somehow don't know which works better to find $Lie(G)$.

I know that if I take $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ then $A^tQA=\begin{pmatrix} a^2-c^2&ab-cd\\ab-cd&b^2-d^2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{!}{=}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$. But I don't know if this helps me further. I thought about If I can find a basis of $G$ and then derive it, I will get a basis of the tangent space and thus one of the Lie algebra.

Can someone help me further?

Comment: Consider a smooth curve $A(s)$ of matrices lying in $G$ such that $A(0)=I$. Then, $A(s)^TQA(s)=Q$. Differentiate with respect to $s$ at $s=0$. The RHS will give $0$, and the LHS will be a sum of two terms by the product rule, in total giving you an equation involving $\dot{A}(0)$ and $Q$. DO NOT expand out the matrix product; just work abstactly with the product rule. This sort of reasoning works in very great generality.

Comment: @peek-a-boo's suggestion is great, but I am in the habit of using the trick of plugging into the defining equation $A=I+\epsilon B$, where the matrices $B$ are the elements of the Lie algebra, and $\epsilon$ is a tiny number that you can think of as satisfying the obvious rules of arithmetic as well as the rule $\epsilon^2=0$. Here you end up with the matrix equation $B^TQ+QB=0$. The method can be justified in various ways. Look up *dual numbers*. It makes perfect sense intuitively as in nearly all differential calculus we think of $\epsilon^2$ as something that can be ignored.

Comment: Anyway, I got $$\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}$$ as the matrix spanning the Lie algebra. Caveat, you should double check, because I haven't had enough coffee yet. It does look like the $\exp(tX)$ recipe only yields matrices in the connected component of $I_2$, as expected.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so you plug in $A$ into $\exp(tA)$? or where did you plug it in?

Comment: No, the elements $B$ of the Lie algebra go into $\exp(tB)$. Yielding
$$\pmatrix{\cosh t&\sinh t\cr\sinh t&\cosh t\cr}.$$ This gives only those elements of $G$ with $a>0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo do I need to find $A(s)$ explicitly or do I only say $A(s)\in G$ is a smooth curve in $G$ s.t. $A(0)=I$? If I need to find it explicitly, how do I do it?

Comment: No you don’t “find it explicitly”. The tangent space at the identity is the set of **all** velocity vectors to arbitrary curves through the identity. So you take an arbitrary curve $A(s)$ with $A(0)=I$, and compute what its velocity vector has to satisfy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find it using your definition.

Let $X\in \mathrm{Lie}(G)$. Then, by definition, $e^{\lambda X}\in G$ $\ \forall \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

So it holds that $e^{\lambda X^t}Qe^{\lambda X}=Q$. Since $G$ is closed in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ we can take derivative with respect to $\lambda$ on both sides and evaluate at $\lambda=0$. This yields $X^tQ=-QX$. Hence, we just showed that $\mathrm{Lie}(G)\subseteq S:=\{X\in M_2(\mathbb{R})\mid X^tQ+QX=0\}$. In particular $S$ is the set of all $2\times2$ matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}0&a \\ a&0\end{bmatrix}$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now we claim that $S\subseteq \mathrm{Lie}(G)$. So, let $X\in S$. Then $X^tQ+QX=0\Rightarrow X^t=-QXQ^{-1}$. Notice that $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$: $$e^{\lambda X^t}Q=e^{-\lambda QXQ^{-1}}Q=Qe^{-\lambda X}Q^{-1}Q=Qe^{-\lambda X} \Rightarrow e^{\lambda X^t}Qe^{-\lambda X}=Q\Rightarrow e^{\lambda X}\in G \Rightarrow X\in \mathrm{Lie}(G).$$

Alternatively, a direct computation, given that $e^{\lambda X^t}=e^{\lambda X}=\begin{bmatrix}\cosh(\lambda a)&-\sinh(\lambda a)\\\sinh(\lambda a)&\cosh(\lambda a)\end{bmatrix}$, gives $e^{\lambda X^t}Qe^{\lambda X}=Q$ for $a\not=0$ (if $a=0$ we get the undetermined case $Q=Q$).

We conclude that $\mathrm{Lie}(G)=S=\{X\in M_2(\mathbb{R})\mid X^tQ+QX=0\}$.

Comment: Or a simple dimension count gives the other inclusion.